# Why Does ActiveChart.SetSourceData Reject Selection?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code shows the runtime 13 error.

```
Sub draw_chart()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Selection
End Sub
```

The following code, however, does not show this error.

```
Sub draw_chart()
    Set i = Selection
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData i
End Sub
```

Why does `ActiveChart.SetSourceData` reject `Selection` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for Chart.SetSourceData method is expression.SetSourceData (Source, PlotBy) where Source is data type Range. In your first you are attempting to pass a ChartArea, whereas in the second you have a Range.

The second would also fail if you happened to have a ChartArea selected.

Comment: ```Selection``` was ```ChartArea```, you mean. I tried to ```ActiveChart.SetSourceData Range(Selection)``` but failed. Is the previous ```Set i = Selection``` the only way to change ```Selection``` to ```Range```?

Comment: Yes. In the first you actively select the chartarea before attempting to pass it to SetSourceData. Selection will be whatever has focus so ensure you set the focus to a range object e.g. with .Select  (not ideal) or directly to a range object e.g. Dim i As Range: Set i = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A2")